# Set boolean back to original state using redux and react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following scenario where I am using a Preloader before my data is being fetched, then on success it sets a boolean to false, and the data is then being pulled in. All this is working fine, but when using a click event and dispatching again which all works fine, the boolean value is not returning to it's originally state, which would be 'true'. Any thoughts on what I need to do reset it back?

App.jsx

```
....

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ fetching: state.flickr.fetching, flickr: state.flickr.flickr })
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({fetchFlickr}, dispatch)

class Prices extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onChange(sorter) {
    console.log('params', sorter);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    socket.on('get-data-back', (data) => {
      let that = this;
      if (data) {
         this.props.fetchFlickr(); 
      }
    })

  }
  handleClick(e) {

    { this.props.fetching ? false : true } ----- Reset my value?
    socket.emit('fetchData');
  }


  render() {
    const { fetching } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Spin spinning={fetching} delay={500} />
     <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>Refresh</button>
      </div>
    )    
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Prices);
```

Reducer.jsx:

```
const initialArray = {flickr: [], fetching: true, fetched: false, error: null}

function flickr(state=initialArray, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "FETCH_FLICKR": {
        return {...state, fetching: true}
      }
      case "FETCH_FLICKR_REJECTED": {
        return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
      }
      case "FETCH_FLICKR_FULFILLED": {
        return {
          ...state,
          fetching: false,
          fetched: true,
          flickr: action.payload,
        }
      }


    return state
}
export default flickr;
```

Comment: On which target did you bind your click event? Also, did you bind your `handleClick` function to the correct `this` context?

Comment: Doh, I just updated the question. It shouldn't necessarily matter however. The event is being triggered and the data is being re-fetched. My boolean however is not being reset back to true...

Comment: Well, what does your fetchData function do? Does it call an action that a reducer can respond to? I think you should dispatch an action from handleClick

Comment: Yes.I thought is also may have been something to do with socket io but nothing there since I just moved it out. I tried dispatching from handleClick method and still no dice...